# Deploy simple nodejs app to my uni linux vm

Tags: node.js, nginx, web-deployment

I have a vm linux machine access from my uni and I have to deploy simple nodejs app to it. I can ssh the vm machine and everything and I have installed Nginx on it but whenever i try to run a simple "hello world" node app and access it from my browser at home i get redirected to other sites online or i get no response.

This is my Nginx config file

```
# the nginx server instance

server {

listen 80;

listen [::]:80;

server_name fff.com www.fff.com;

access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.com.log;



# pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers

# and much more can be added, see nginx config options

location / {

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;



proxy_pass http://app_fff/;

proxy_redirect off;

}

}
```

and my hello world app

```
var http = require('http');



http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

res.end('Hello World\n');

}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

I run the app and i can curl it from another ssh but when i go to fff.com i either get site can't be reached or get redirected to a normal website.

What am i doing wrong??? How can I type host this stupid app on my uni linux vm and access it from my browser at home??

Comment: This is going to be very difficult for the community to answer, as a lot of factors can be at play here. What does the networking infrastructure look like? Does the server have a path to the internet? Can you `ping` the server from outside the network?

Comment: For starters, it looks as though you've configured your NodeJS application to only listen to requests coming in for `127.0.0.1`, which is a `localhost` loopback address that *should* only be routed correctly when attempting to access from the machine itself, as you've described above.

Comment: @esqew that’s appropriate since his NGINX server is sitting on the same box, though.  For the OP, where have you defined the upstream service “app_fff”? It’s not present in the config file you posted.

Comment: Ok so I'm in my place accessing the VM using VPN and ssh via the address of the vm. I installed nodejs and nginx, then wrote a simple nodejs app and run it successfully from within the VM and now I want to let people access it from the web browser so I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy. What I don't understand is how the reverse proxy works and what's the link between the address of my simple node app and the address I want to use to access the app from the browser?  The VM has Linux running on it